# why kubernetes dashboard could not list resources the first time to login

Tags: kubernetes

I am using this helm 3 command to install kubernetes v1.16.0 dashboard in terminal:

```
helm install kubernetes-dashboard stable/kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
```

but when I login the kuberetetes dashboard from browser,it shows error message like this:

[image]

what is the problem? what should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kubernetes-dashboard service account does not have sufficient privileges which is why your are getting that.

First create a simple user with cluster-admin cluster role and get the secret using below command

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

And then  find out the token using this way

```
kubectl get secret $(kubectl get serviceaccount  admin-user -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}" -n kube-system) -o jsonpath="{.data.token}" -n kube-system | base64 --decode
```